# JS Adding property to object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a property to an object the following way:

```
function methodA(client, page){
    Object.defineProperty(client, 'name', {
        value: page,
        writable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
      });

    methodB(client)
}
```

When I do a console log of `client.name` in methodB  it returns undefined. Can someone point me out what I'm doing wrong ? I'm new to JS.

Comment: `client.name = page;` would probably be easier

Comment: Where is it returning undefined?

Comment: Maybe you are not passing a second argument to methodA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving your code some dummy values it seems to work perfectly well. The error must be elsewhere. Run the snippet and see:

```js
function methodA(client, page){
    Object.defineProperty(client, 'name', {
        value: page,
        writable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
      });

    methodB(client)
}

function methodB(client) {
    console.log(client);
    console.log("Name property is: "+client.name);
}

methodA({a:9}, 12);
```

Maybe try to make a snippet the gives the same error (you might stumble into the solution by yourself in doing so)

Comment: I tried that and to check that it was working after I defined the property, and I try to client.name, value comes as undefined

Comment: I've edited the snippet for the console to also log specifically "client.name". It works. Does the snippet not work on your computer?

Comment: Thanks a lot on the response I had a typo on my code!